# http запрос из angular в react axios

Tags: reactjs, http, post, angular

Есть функция на angular 1.7.5, которая отправляет http запрос, http запрос функции возвращает observable (насколько я понимаю), вот она:

```
login(credentials): Observable<any> {
        const data = {
            username: credentials.username,
            password: credentials.password,
            rememberMe: credentials.rememberMe
        };

        return this.http.post(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/authenticate', data, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(map(authenticateSuccess.bind(this)));

        function authenticateSuccess(resp) {
            const bearerToken = resp.headers.get('Authorization');
            if (bearerToken && bearerToken.slice(0, 7) === 'Bearer ') {
                const jwt = bearerToken.slice(7, bearerToken.length);
                this.storeAuthenticationToken(jwt, credentials.rememberMe);
                return jwt;
            }
        }
    }
```

у меня не получается переписать эту функцию в react, чтобы она работала (основная проблема - http запрос)
Вот то, что я делаю:

```
login(){
        const data = {
            username: this.model.login,
            password: this.model.pwd,
            rememberMe: localStorage.getItem('rememberMe')
        };
        return axios.post('authenticate', data, { observe: 'response' }).then(() => {(map(authenticateSuccess.bind(this)))}).catch(err=>{
            events.alert.next({type: 'danger', text:'Не удалось найти пользователя с соответствующими данными'});
            console.log(err)
        });

        function authenticateSuccess(resp) {
            const bearerToken = resp.headers.get('Authorization');
            if (bearerToken && bearerToken.slice(0, 7) === 'Bearer ') {
                const jwt = bearerToken.slice(7, bearerToken.length);
                this.storeAuthenticationToken(jwt, this.model.rememberMe);
                return jwt;
            }
        }
    }
    storeAuthenticationToken(jwt, rememberMe) {
        if (rememberMe) {
            this.localStorage.store('authenticationToken', jwt);
        } else {
            this.sessionStorage.store('authenticationToken', jwt);
        }
    }
```

при then в http запросе логина не происходит, вообще по нажатию кнопки войти ничего не происходит, если же в http запросе написать pipe (как в angular версии) (надо учитывать ещё то, что определение pipe я попробовал закинуть, установил rxjs) то выходит ошибка `TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11___default.a.post(...).pipe is not a function`

насколько я понимаю, в ангуляре http возвращяет Observable, а axios возвращает Promise, соответственно, нужно переделать работу с Observable в работу с Promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
login(){
        const data = {
            username: this.model.login,
            password: this.model.pwd,
            rememberMe: localStorage.getItem('rememberMe') || false
        };
        return axios.post('authenticate', data, { observe: 'response' })
            .then(authenticateSuccess.bind(this))
            .catch(err=>{
                events.alert.next({type: 'danger', text:'Не удалось найти пользователя с соответствующими данными'});
                localStorage.clear('rememberMe');
                this.rememberMe = false;
                alert('Неверная пара логин\пароль')
            });
        function authenticateSuccess(resp) {
            this.rememberMe = false;
            this.setState({
                open : false
            })
            currentUser.next(data.username);
            data.rememberMe ?
                localStorage.setItem('user',data.username) :
                sessionStorage.setItem('user',data.username);
            const bearerToken = resp.headers.authorization;
            if (bearerToken && bearerToken.slice(0, 7) === 'Bearer ') {
                const jwt = bearerToken.slice(7, bearerToken.length);
                this.storeAuthenticationToken(jwt, data.rememberMe);
                return jwt;
            }
        }
    }
```

так работает